# Lombok @Builder on class with generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, lombok, builder

Is there a way to use Lombok's `@Builder` with Java generics?

```
@Builder
public class Response<T> {
    private String status;
    private long total;
    private List<T> page;
}
```

Later in a service that handles requests from controller:

```
long total = getTotalItemsCount();
List<Article> page = getPage();

Response<Article> response =
    Response.builder()
        .status("ok")
        .total(total)
        .page(page); // error on this line
```

It's not possible to call `page` method:

> The method `page(List<Object>)` in the type
> `Response.ResponseBuilder<Object>` is not applicable for the arguments
> (`List<Article>`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to specify a "type witness", the 2nd `<Article>` part below:

```
Response<Article> response =
        Response.<Article>builder() // here
            .status("ok")
            .total(total)
            .page(page)
            .build();
```

This is really nothing to do with Lombok, but a shortcoming of Java's type inference. It cannot infer through the chain of method calls that `builder()` needs to create a Response of type Article, even though it's ultimately assigned to a variable of that type.

The type witness is a way of overriding the inference and specifying the generic type parameter explicitly.